# Limit the task list by filtering by directory in Netbeans 7.1

Tags: php, netbeans, task, todo, netbeans-7.1

I am looking to filter the visible tasks by directory so that I don't get all the @todos from external libraries. But It's not quite working how I expected.

Below is an example of what I have tried.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use :

> Location  Begins With (Case sensitive)  < absolute_path_of_your_netbeans_workspace >/< project_name >/src

You seem to be on Windows so **absolute_path_of_your_netbeans_workspace** should start with something like **C:/**.

Comment: It's important to note that NetBeans expects `C:/` literally; **C:\\** will not work.